# Comparing mapped items for additional output using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, lodash

I have a standard mapped element using React. My render is below:

```
    render() {
    const { timeLineData } = this.props;
    const dateOrder = _.sortBy(timeLineData, function (o) { return new moment(o.createdDate) }).reverse();

    return (
        <div className="timeline-section">
            {dateOrder.map((status, index) => (
                <div key={index}> 
                    <div className="timeline-badge"></div>
                    <div className="timeline-panel">
                        <p>{moment(status.createdDate).format('ll')}</p>
                        <h2 className="timeline-title"><strong>{status.status}</strong></h2>
                        <p>{progressed}?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

My data called `timeLineData` is being ordered by data and being mapped in that order. Here is the output:

```
timeLineData: [
0:{
createdDate: "2018-06-08T00:00:00"
status: "ON TARGET"}
1:{
createdDate: "2017-06-08T00:00:00"
status: "FOLLOW"}
2:{
createdDate: "2016-06-08T00:00:00"
status: "DO NOT FOLLOW"}
]
```

My UI renders a timeline thats ordered by date and shows a status of progess. I would like an additional field on my UI to notify the user if they have progressed/or regressed from a previous date. The 3 status' in the example are [1:'ON TARGET', 2:'FOLLOW', 3:'DO NOT FOLLOW'] these are in order of progression e.g `ON TARGET` is a progression from `FOLLOW`.

So I need the mapping process to look at the status of the item previous and render an attribute if there has been progression, regression or no change. I imagine that the rank would need to be set and each status given a value, then a lookup whilst the mapping was taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand your `map` parameters to include `array`, you can easily check the previous item using `index`. Below is just a basic outline of the sort of thing you could do. I've included a bit that checks to see if you're at the the beginning of the array as it is required that you have a previous item to compare to. Hope it helps!

```
{dateOrder.map((status, index, array) => {
    // Setup goes here
    const previousStatus = array[index-1].status
    // If previousStatus returns undefined, it can be used to check if there's a previous item to compare to.
    return (
        // The rest of your code
        {(previousStatus && previousStatus === 'something')
            ? null
            : <div>{"The thing that you want"}</div>} 
    )
}}
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for., but when I apply this my status becomes undefined. {dateOrder.map((status, index, array) => {...

Comment: Ok, I think I might need to remove the .status after the array[index-1]

Comment: Have you got it working? Please can you show what the dateOrder array looks like in your question as it would make it easier to know how you're going to access the status in each object.